# Visual Studio 2017 hiding project root files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio (2017) I have a project with a very large number of files at the root of the project as well as some folders. I want to keep the project open in the solution explorer as I'm working with files in some of the folders of this project. I'm also working with several other projects in the solution, several of which are placed below this large project in the list. However, due to the number of items that are in this project's root, I end up needing to scroll quite a long way to see the items that I *do* want to work in.

Is there any way -extensions included - to hide/collapse project root items (possibly into a virtual folder)?

Comment: It is not obvious why you can't move the unpopular items into a folder where the sun don't shine.  Or break this giant one into multiple projects.  Try it, tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this project is a website and the elements at the root are all web pages and dynamically-loaded controls (the mechanism of which relies on paths specified in code). I've considered moving the items to another folder but I'm not the sole owner of the project and I'd be concerned about the potential for problems to arise. I was just hoping for a simple solution that doesn't require changing the layout of the project itself.